# php code refused to insert value into database

Tags: php, mysql

PHP code is refusing to insert a particular field into database. All other field insert into database apart from:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="recip" id="recip" placeholder="To"/>
</div>
```

Here is the code that sends the message:

*SEND.PHP*

```
include('../../dbconnect.php');
{
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))


$email = ($_POST['recip']);
$title = ($_POST['title']);
$message = ($_POST['compose-textarea']);
//$role = admin;
//$msg = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
//$days = str_replace('/', '-',$_POST['endtime']);

//We check if the recipient exists
         {

            //if it has the correct format whether the email has already exist

            //$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE email = '$recip'";
            //$result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error());
            //if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)
            {
           //     $_SESSION['usermsg'] = "<center><div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>This Email is already used.</div></center>";
            //  header("location: register.php");
//exit;
            }
        }
        //else
        {
            //this error will set if the email format is not correct
         //  $_SESSION['usermsg'] = "<center><div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Your email is not valid.</div></center>";
        //  header("location: register.php");
//exit;
        }


    $sql = "INSERT INTO messages (to_user, subject,message)
                   VALUES ('$email','$title','$message')";

   // $sql = ('insert into pm (id, id2, title, user1,user2, message, timestamp, user1read, user2read)
            //values("'.$id.'", "1", "'.$title.'",  "'.$_SESSION['userid'].'","'.$sql1['recipid'].'", "'.$message.'", "'.time().'", "yes", "no")');

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

   header("location: compose.php");
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
}

/// $sql = ('insert into pm (id, id2, title, user1, user2, message, timestamp, user1read, user2read)values("'.$id.'", "1", "'.$title.'", "'.$_SESSION['userid'].'", "'.$dn1['recipid'].'", "'.$message.'", "'.time().'", "yes", "no")');
 ?>
```

but when i change the `$email` to`$title` it send the value
i dont know what am doing wrong please i need your help as have been on this particular issue for a long time
please i know this is the basic of php,but please be nice smile:)

below is the form

```
form name="my_form" action="SEND.php" method="POST">
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                  <h3 class="box-title">Compose New Message</h3>
                </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="recip" id="recip" placeholder="To"/>
                    </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Subject:"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea id="compose-textarea" name="compose-textarea" class="form-control" style="height: 300px">
                      <h1><u>Heading Of Message</u></h1>
                      <h4>Subheading</h4>
                      <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure? On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee</p>
                      <ul>
                        <li>List item one</li>
                        <li>List item two</li>
                        <li>List item three</li>
                        <li>List item four</li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>Thank you,</p>
                      <p>John Doe</p>
                    </textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                      <i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i> Attachment
                      <input type="file" name="attachment"/>
                    </div>
                    <p class="help-block">Max. 32MB</p>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                <div class="box-footer">
                  <div class="pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Draft</button>
                 <button onclick=" $('#compose-textarea').val($('.Editor-editor').html());" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Send</button>
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Discard</button>
                </div><!-- /.box-footer -->
              </div><!-- /. box -->
            </form>
```

please dont worry about my security (mysq injection)will work on that my self just help with the current problem.thanks

Comment: Could it be that because you are not paying attention to SQL injection. The data you are sending had a special char in it and is causing the failure. What is the error you are getting? Look at the SQL that is generated to make sure that would work.

Comment: am not getting any error message

Comment: If it's not inserting.  It's not running or there is an error somewhere. You just cant see it. I would echo out my sql statement and run it manually with some other front end. Did you check your web servers error log?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your SQL table and ensure that the column 'to_user' is set to accept VARCHAR or TEXT .

Comment: my column is in order, if i change  the variable to $title it works but i dont know why $email those not work